# what does "explicitly locking" filesystem in Windows mean and how do I do that in my program?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-vista

this article about new security features in Vista http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says "write operations on a disk handle will succeed if: .... sectors being written to fall within a mounted file system that is locked explicitly "

What does it mean for a Windows file system to be "locked explicitly"?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you open the volume (`CreateFile`), and lock it using [FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code.
You can do that for non-system volumes only